# Check if username already exist in DB

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I trying to validate username field in register form and to check if the selected username already exist in DB but doesn't work as expected. I'm not sure how to fix this. Here is the source

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = :username";
$sq = $pdo->prepare($query);
$sq->execute(array(
         ':username'    => $username                                
        ));
$res=$sq->fetch();
if (!$res) {
    echo ' Database Error Occured ';
}
else { echo "username already exist in database"; }

if ($res === 0) {
    $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $pdo->beginTransaction();
    try 
    {
         $sql = "INSERT INTO users ( username, password, email, path)
                            VALUES (:username, :password, :email, :path)";

                $q = $pdo->prepare($sql);
                $q->execute(array(
                    ':username' => $username,
                    ':password' => $password,
                    ':email'    => $email,
                    ':path'     => $path                                
                    ));                 

                $lastInsertID = $pdo->lastInsertId();
                $sql = $pdo->prepare("UPDATE users SET level=:user_id WHERE user_id=:user_id");
                $sql->execute(array(
                    ':user_id'  => $lastInsertID
                    ));
                $pdo->commit();     
     }
```

What is happening is when I click on submit button If I'm entered username that exist I got `username already exist in database` but if I enter another which doesn't exist I got  `Database Error Occured`

Comment: What does `fetch()` return in the case of an empty record set? I suspect it's returning a boolean `false`. Try using `rowCount` instead - that will let you differentiate between a boolean `false` if the query failes, and `0` to say that the query worked (but returned no data)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to replace this

```
 if (!$res) {
        echo ' Database Error Occured ';
    }
    else { echo "username already exist in database"; }
if ($res === 0) {
```

by this

```
if ($res) {
    echo "username already exist in database";
}else{
```

Answer (score 2):

```
if(1 < $res->rowCount()){
    print('username already exist');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Because `$sq->fetch()` returns `FALSE` (it does not exists). You should change check to:

```
if ($res) {
    echo "username already exist in database";
}
```

And

```
if ($res === FALSE) {
// Username does not exist
}
```